# regex start with 10 or 20 followed by x amount of numbers

Tags: regex

I want to build a RegEx that will allow the value to start with 10 or 20 followed by numbers only

This is what I did so far:  `^[10][0-9]+$`

This will allow the input value to start with 10 followed by numbers. How can i do it so that the input can start with 10 or 20 followed by any numbers?

Comment: You seem to have a bit of a mis-understanding - the Regex you provided above allows the input value to start with ***either*** a `1` **OR** `0`, not `10` specifically.

Answer (score 3):

You can use alternative matching group:

```
^(10|20)[0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex will match any string starting with *either `1` or `0`*, followed by some amount of digits.
You are looking for something like

```
^[12]0[0-9]+$
```

Or

```
^(10|20)[0-9]+$
```